# Modify an html text using bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing an script to translate the visible text of an html file from english to another language. And i can extract the text but i dont know how to put it back where it came from.

I'd like to know if there is a way using bs4 or other scraping lib to grab a block of text or something human readable, modify it, and then put it right were it came from something like

```
with open('../folder/index.html') as inf:
    txt = inf.read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt)

'''for each block of text in the soup, extract it, translate it and put it back'''

with open('../folder/new_index.html','w') as f:
    f.write(soup)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently your whole html file is saved in the variable soup. Try to do something like that:

#make list of lines

`soupList = soup.split("\n")`

#get line that you want to modify

`lineToModify = soupList[<indexOfLine>]`

#Do something with the line

`modifiedLine = lineToModify + "hello"`

#and put it back in the list

`soupList[<indexOfLine>] = modifiedLine`

#put the html file together again and write it#

`soup = soupList.join("\n")`

`with open('../folder/new_index.html','w') as f:`

`f.write(soup)`